# Deleting versus merging questions

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16703) was removed by a moderator after it had been closed as an exact duplicate. But it did have 4 answers, the first one with 6 upvotes, so it seems to be valuable. Why not merge the question with the other one, so interesting answers don't get lost?

Comment: For those that are confused by some of the situation, when I merged it no longer makes sense to delete, instead it is now a place holder for a different search term. All can see it now.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently deleting questions that were closed over a year ago. This is a regular cleanup that was done. This was deleted 6/27/2012. It was closed July 13,2011.

Why is it now that people want to save answers, not a single request in 1 year. If you think a merge is worthwhile please send us a flag, we can merge if it makes sense to bring the questions over. In this case the migrate is worth it, I agree, sorry I did not catch that. I was reading the questions to verify a lock would not be more logical instead of a delete but did not think of checking for merges.

I have performed the merge now, just flag a moderator in the future!

Comment: My attention was drawn to it because it showed -10 on my rep page (-10 for 2 upvotes? Shouldn't that be -20?) Anyway, at the time I didn't flag that often yet, you know that I do now. I'll try to keep an eye on it. ([Another question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19820) you removed had only 1 answer with 1 upvote, probably not worth saving.) Thanks.

Comment: @stevenvh, I dont have an answer for the -10, now you probably avoid answering questions that will be closed to the extent you know about the duplicates. Just let me know, as a moderator it is mostly my job to do paperwork. I agree on that second answer, you have a much higher quality answer on the question that one was closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: Deleting crappy questions I understand, but you're deleting questions merely because they're duplicates?  That seems needlessly destructive to me.

Comment: @endolith, I am deleting many of the very old closed questions. This is not the first time we have done it. It keeps many of them from cluttering up the site, they all have had low activity and low views. If they are still drawing people in regularly I move it to a lock instead of a close.